# Q: Promisify Synchronous operations for chaining promises?

Tags: promise, q, chaining

Is there any merit in promisifying synchronous operations so that by design they can be chained in onSuccess or onError callbacks?

Eg:

```
function loadSettings(path) {
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        return Q(fsJson.loadSync(path));
    }
    return new Q.defer().reject('No local settings!');
}

doingSomethingFirst()
    .then(loadSettings, obtainSettings)
    .then(doSomethingWithSettings)
    .done()
```

What's best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, moreover, it gives the false impression that these methods are async so you or other developers might call them and expect that the method is not undermining the entire io.js/node.js concurrency model by performing sync IO.

I recommend that you either make these functions not return promises or make them perform async IO. Also note that your method has a race condition (what if the file is deleted between when you check it exists and when you try to access it?)

Comment: @gruenbaum Thanks for the response.  As to the race condition, how to add safety to loading synchronously? Try/catch the call to `fsJson.loadSync(path)`, then check there's actually a file, before returning?

Comment: Yes, ask for forgiveness and not permission.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this particular chain will literally work exactly the same even if you wrote `loadSettings` like this:

```
function loadSettings(path) {
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        return fsJson.loadSync(path);
    }
    throw 'No local settings!';
}
```

Note that it's a horrible practice to reject with strings or throw strings so ideally you'd want `new Error('No local settings!')` instead. I mean just imagine if that error actually happened and it was just a string - you would have no idea how or where the error really happened.

Comment: Well, _technically_ in bluebird you would, wouldn't you? (Still it's a horrible idea to throw strings, and there's the race condition issue, and undermining io/node etc).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum no iirc it was removed, in many cases the trace was useless actually

Comment: Really? So if you throw a string with long stack traces bluebird won't generate a long stack trace like it used to? That's a shame since sometimes you're forced to use external libraries that return promises or code that uses them and sometimes they throw strings because they hate developers. Doing `.nodeify` and `.promisify` on that seems kind of dumb :D

Comment: Why was it removed? Perf?

Comment: internal complexity for something that is not really needed

Comment: Well, in theory I think it's a useful feature but in practice I haven't noticed this until now - so there's that :)